# How to incorporate angular javascript shown below in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been trying unsuccessfully to create a dynamic(chained) drop down list for many days in codeigniter, have gone throught lots of tutorials but one way or the other failed to do it. My third post on the same topic over here. I have found [this](http://devzone.co.in/simple-example-of-dependable-dropdowns-cascading-dropdowns-using-angularjs/) tutorial(code) which gives [this](http://lab.devzone.co.in/angular-js-dropdowns/)output which is what I am exactly trying to achieve. Will I be able to use this codes in codeigniter 2.x. I did a bit of google search and found [this](http://tamtech.co.in/autopopulate-dependent-dropdown-on-change-using-angular-js-codeigniter/) but I fail to understand the part when the tutorial reach AppController.js portion (dont know where and how it is used). Please someone tell me how I can have a similar dropdown list? 
Thank You for the support!

Comment: We're not here to write or explain tutorials.  We're here to answer very specific questions.  Please review:  [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this question really has nothing to do with `php` or `codeigniter`

Answer (score 1):

Creating a dropdown is a frontend question and not something the backend framework (in your case codeigniter) have anything to do with. What you want to do is write some JavaScript code that can dynamically show and hide the dropdown.

The first tutorial you link to describe how you can make such a menu using the frontend library AngularJS. So to answer your question if you can do this with codeigniter: yes.

Comment: Thank you @Knarf, that means the drop down list will be displayed by angularJS and the items selected from the list will be updated by some php codes. But where do I use(place) the AngularJS files in the codeigniter project folder.

Comment: You should have a folder named "js" under application assets.